# What's the difference between 遭到 and 遭受?

Tags: difference

The verbs 遭到 and 遭受 both mean to suffer harm. Which one is the most commonly used?

Are these two sentences both correct?

生态平衡遭到破坏。

生态平衡遭受破坏。

What's the difference between this two sentences? Can I use them interchangeably?

Answer (score 1):

- 遭: encounter; suffer; receive
- 到:  verbal particle to indicate the result of an action.
- 遭到 (receive; encounter) is a verb 遭 (encounter) +  a verb particle 到. There is only one verb 遭.

~

- 遭: receive; encounter; suffer
- 受: receive
- 遭受 is a compound word (single word) for 'receive; suffer; undergo'

Since 遭受 is a single verb, you can add verb particle 到 after it to indicate the result and write 遭受到.

On the other hand, 遭到 is a verb and its verb particle, you can omit the verb particle and only write 遭 when you don't need to emphasize the result of the verb

The following are all valid sentences. They all mean the same:

> 生态平衡遭受破坏。(the compound word verb 遭受 is more specific than the single character verb 遭)

> 生态平衡遭受到破坏。 (the verb particle 到 indicates the verb 遭受 is completed/ received a result

> 生态平衡遭破坏。(using the literary single character verb 遭 make it sounds more classical/ literary)

> 生态平衡受破坏。(using the colloquial single character verb 受 make it sounds more modern/ colloquial)

> 生态平衡遭到破坏。(the verb particle 到 indicates the verb 遭 is completed/ received a result, also make it sounds more modern/ colloquial)

> *You can replace 遭到 (more literary) with 受到 (more colloquial)*

Comment: 他们的试验遭受失败，还要从头做起。 ‎is this natural?if it is wrong,please tell
me why

Comment: 遭受 is not needed in '他们的试验失败， because 失败 can be a verb for fail. 还 in 要从头做起 is not needed because there is no indication in the context suggested 'also' is needed

Comment: 他们的试验遭受挫折 (setback) is more appropriate than  他们的试验遭受挫敗 (defeat)   -- we don't get defeat (n) in an experiment, we get setback (n)

Comment: 它们的试验遭受失败，还要从头做起。 i search in dictionary, it means：the experiment ended in failure ,so 遭到 is used .If 遭受 or 受到 is used ,it stresses the influence from a foreign force.However ,the failure of experiment has no such meaning .

Comment: I have came across this sentence on the Internet：在口语中，除非表示强调，混用这两个词一般不会造成歧义。  i am very confused。

Comment: I'd like to make is that the word 遭 itself can actually represent 遭到, 遭受, or 遭受到 in almost any context if we only consider semantic factors, and that the only restraint is the rhythm.

Comment: @jinglingmen Quite accurate. Unless one wants to 鑽牛角尖 :)